# Find Users with two or more records

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Got a simple app running. Our app has bins table in DB that has a user_id row .. logges the Users ID from Users model so that each bin belongs to a user ID with user_id belonging to that User.

Anyways, I'm trying to use Rails console to run FIND on the Bins and locate all users with 3 or more Bins.

So far I've tried both Bins and Users as such;

```
user = User.all
Bin.find(:all, :conditions => ['user.id = bins_user_id'])
```

However its not really bringing up anything other then "user.id" doesn't exist.

Comment: try using .having("count(*) > ?", 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a `joins` on `Users` with `Bin`...  Then something like:

`User.joins(:bins).group("user.id").having("count(bins.user_id) > 2")`

Which will yield the following SQL:

`SELECT "users.*" from "users" INNER JOIN "bins" ON "bins"."user_id" = "users"."id" GROUP BY users.id HAVING count(bins.user_id) > 2`

I *think* this will work, but it will at least git you close. I tried this in a Rails app with similar data to what you're describing, and it returned the results I expected.

Comment: close but I'm getting error on the group `no such column user.id` I'm guessing its because user.id column isn't in Bins but rather auto assigned Users.

Comment: I fixed a bug above, but it shouldnt' matter...  Does a `Bin` have a FK to `User`, like `user_id`?